# WatchKit-Distinguish among tables in table(table, didSelectRowAtIndex)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I have 2 tables in my `WKInterfaceController`. Clicking on their rows will push to different `WKInterfaceController`. I need to use `override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int)` because I need to pass a context object.

How do I tell which `WKInterfaceTable` row is clicked?

Something like this:

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    // If condition A is satisfied
    {
        presentControllerWithName("WKControllerA", context: self)
    }
    else
    {
        presentControllerWithName("WKControllerB", context: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just check the `table` and `rowIndex` like this:

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int){

    if table==myTable1 && rowIndex==myIndex {

            //do something

    } else if table==myTable2  && rowIndex==myIndex2  {

            //do something else

    }
}
```